# Installation of openoffice 4.0 for open erp

Tags: odoo, openoffice.org

i download open office 4.0 and i provide username = amber last name= xyz 
and initials=ABC but next button always disabled

can any one tell me plz where it the problem?

Answer (score 0):

FOr configuring openoffice with openerp for report generation.please go through the below link http://openerp.co.za/7/reports/reporting.html